# How can I set processor affinity to a thread or a Task in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Can we set two threads or two tasks to execute with different processor affinity in a C# application?

I have read about `SetThreadAffinityMask`, but have found no example of how that should be used.

Alternatively, is there any way for TPL (Task Parallel Library) to execute two threads/Tasks with high priority to use 100% CPU?

Answer (score 51):

`Process` and `ProcessThread` objects have a `ProcessorAffinity` property of `IntPtr` type that can be directly manipulated to read/change affinity for up to 64 processors:

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
```

```cs
Process proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
long affinityMask = 0x000F; // use only any of the first 4 available processors
proc.ProcessorAffinity = (IntPtr)affinityMask;
 
ProcessThread thread = proc.Threads[0];
affinityMask = 0x0002; // use only the second processor, despite availability
thread.ProcessorAffinity = (IntPtr)affinityMask;
```

You can also use the thread's `IdealProcessor` property to allow the scheduler to prefer running the thread on a specified processor (without guarantee).

Yes, it's that easy :)

Reference: [ProcessThread.ProcessorAffinity Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processthread.processoraffinity#System_Diagnostics_ProcessThread_ProcessorAffinity)

Comment: Q: "Can we set two thread or two task to execute with different processor affinity in C# Application?" Notice that the OP asks for different _threads_ in the same _process_. So the question is not about  _process_, but _thread_ affinity.

Comment: There is `Thread.SetProcessorAffinity()` but it only applies to XNA for the Xbox 360. There is no OOTB solution in vanilla .NET, as far as I know.

Comment: @andras: Good point, I guess I missed the mark a bit. There is a way to do this for threads too, and I edited my example accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. ;) It could be made even more useful if we could get the `ProcessThread` of the current `Thread` so that we could use this on the current thread and then get a nice `using()` construct to revert to the original affinity at the end of the block. That would be great. ;)

Comment: also i've found this code in internet that probably can be used https://code.google.com/p/disruptor-net/source/browse/trunk/Source/Disruptor/Affinity/ProcessorAffinity.cs?r=128

Answer (score 6):

Actually, .NET Framework and Windows manage the threads pretty well, distributing them evenly on every processor. However, the distribution of threads **can** be manipulated manually using `Process` and `ProcessThread`.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace ThreadTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Get the our application's process.
            Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

            //Get the processor count of our machine.
            int cpuCount = Environment.ProcessorCount;
            Console.WriteLine("CPU Count : {0}", cpuCount);

            //Since the application starts with a few threads, we have to
            //record the offset.
            int offset = process.Threads.Count;
            Thread[] threads = new Thread[cpuCount];
            Console.WriteLine(process.Threads.Count);
            LogThreadIds(process);

            //Create and start a number of threads that equals to
            //our processor count.
            for (int i = 0; i < cpuCount; ++i)
            {
                Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Calculation))
                { IsBackground = true };
                t.Start();
            }

            //Refresh the process information in order to get the newest
            //thread list.
            process.Refresh();
            Console.WriteLine(process.Threads.Count);
            LogThreadIds(process);

            //Set the affinity of newly created threads.
            for (int i = 0; i < cpuCount; ++i)
            {
                //process.Threads[i + offset].ProcessorAffinity = (IntPtr)(1L << i);
                //The code above distributes threads evenly on all processors.
                //But now we are making a test, so let's bind all the threads to the
                //second processor.
                process.Threads[i + offset].ProcessorAffinity = (IntPtr)(1L << 1);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static void Calculation()
        {
            //some extreme loads.
            while (true)
            {
                Random rand = new Random();
                double a = rand.NextDouble();
                a = Math.Sin(Math.Sin(a));
            }
        }
        static void LogThreadIds(Process proc)
        {
            //This will log out all the thread id binded to the process.
            //It is used to test whether newly added threads are the latest elements
            //in the collection.
            Console.WriteLine("===Thread Ids===");
            for (int i = 0; i < proc.Threads.Count; ++i)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(proc.Threads[i].Id);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("===End of Thread Ids===");
        }
    }
}
```

Now check the task manager, we can see that that the second processor is taking all the work loads.
[The task manager window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVN3b.png)

Comment: example is wrong, `process.Threads[i + offset].ProcessorAffinity = (IntPtr)(1L << 1);` sets the processor affinity to processor 1 only

Comment: @FabioAngela *But now we are making a test, so let's bind all the threads to the second processor.* I don't see how my example contradicts the description.

Comment: my bad, commented code above reports i and not 1 so it's fine (read both as 1 at first)

Answer (score 3):

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessorAffinity = (System.IntPtr)2;
```

Comment: Although this is answer to different question, it worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: This will change the affinity of whole application (process) effectively assigning same affinity to all threads of this app. OP asked about changing affinity of 2 threads within same app.

Answer (score 2):

Actually OS is capable of load balancing your cores/processors but if you want to do it explicitly use mentioned via [PInvoke](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/SetThreadAffinityMask.html). You pass id of thread (not managed one!) and mask - the bit array of cores.

Comment: how do you test if it actually works?

Answer (score 0):

The following example from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread.processoraffinity(v=vs.110).aspx) shows how to set the `ProcessorAffinity` property for an instance of `Notepad` to the first processor.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ProcessThreadIdealProcessor
{
    class Program
    {
     static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        // Make sure there is an instance of notepad running.
        Process[] notepads = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
        if (notepads.Length == 0)
            Process.Start("notepad");
            ProcessThreadCollection threads;
            //Process[] notepads; 
            // Retrieve the Notepad processes.
            notepads = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad");
            // Get the ProcessThread collection for the first instance
            threads = notepads[0].Threads;
            // Set the properties on the first ProcessThread in the collection
            threads[0].IdealProcessor = 0;
            threads[0].ProcessorAffinity = (IntPtr)1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Copy and pasted from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread.processoraffinity.aspx. Source should be referenced...

Answer (score -1):

I want to share this code, showing how to do it with TPL.

With threads,

```
        using System;
        using System.Diagnostics;
        using System.Threading;
        
        static void Fibonacci(int n)
        {
            int a = 0, b = 1, c = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                c = a + b;
                a = b;
                b = c;
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}: Fibonacci({n}) = {c}");
        }
        
        int processorCount = Environment.ProcessorCount;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < processorCount; i++)
        {
            int processorNum = i;
            Thread thread = new Thread(() => Fibonacci(processorNum * 10));
            
            // Set processor affinity for each thread
            thread.ProcessorAffinity = (IntPtr)(1 << processorNum);
            
            thread.Start();
        }
```

With TPL (Below code will not work, just a failed attempt),

```
        using System;
        using System.Diagnostics;
        using System.Threading.Tasks;
        
        int processorCount = Environment.ProcessorCount;
        
        Task[] tasks = new Task[processorCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < processorCount; i++)
        {
            int processorNum = i;
            tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Fibonacci(processorNum * 10), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
        }

        // Set processor affinity for each task
        ProcessThreadCollection currentThreads = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads;
        for (int i = 0; i < processorCount; i++)
        {
            ProcessThread assignedThread = null;
            foreach (ProcessThread thread in currentThreads)
            {
                # Problem here: Is possible to find out TPL task's thread ID, after it started? And then assign processor affinity after startNew?
                if (thread.Id == tasks[i].Id)
                {
                    assignedThread = thread;
                    break;
                }
            }
            
            if (assignedThread != null)
            {
                int processorNum = i;
                assignedThread.ProcessorAffinity = (IntPtr)(1 << processorNum);
            }
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I am very suspicious about the *"with TPL"* section. Specifically the condition `if (thread.Id == tasks[i].Id)` looks like comparing for equality apples to oranges. My suggestion is to remove it, and keep just the *"with threads"* section.

Comment: I think you're correct. You think it's possible to find out TPL task's thread ID, after it started? And then assign processor affinity after startNew?

Comment: One idea is to configure the current thread internally, using the `Thread.CurrentThread` property. Another is to write a custom `TaskScheduler` that has a `ProcessorAffinity` property, which then runs its tasks on dedicated threads configured accordingly. As a starting point see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570579/is-it-possible-always-to-force-a-new-thread-with-task/68929857#68929857).