# How to start a thread on a specific core?

Tags: c#, multithreading, affinity, cpu-cores

I have a quad core CPU, and lets say I always want to start a `Thread` on the second core.

Is that possible in C#?

Comment: See [How Can I Set Processor Affinity in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510593/how-can-i-set-processor-affinity-in-net).

Comment: Check these discussions:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/a55733db-cac0-4ccb-a3cc-a584742b41f9/ http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10156145/thread-affinity.aspx http://www.gamedev.net/topic/477794-c-multi-threading-quad-core-thread-affinity/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Can I Set Processor Affinity in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510593/how-can-i-set-processor-affinity-in-net)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. Check out [`ProcessorAffinity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.processoraffinity.aspx) for Windows or [`SetProcessorAffinity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.setprocessoraffinity.aspx) for XBox XNA.

This is also discussed on another [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510593/how-can-i-set-processor-affinity-in-net/2510708#2510708).

Answer (score 8):

Yes, take a look at the [`ProcessorAffinity property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread.processoraffinity.aspx) for the thread.

Answer (score 2):

Set `ProcessorAffinity` of the process:

```
0x0001 = 0000 0001 - run on 1st core
                 ↑
0x0002 = 0000 0010 - run on 2nd core
                ↑
0x0003 = 0000 0011 - run on 1st and 2nd core
                ↑↑
0x0004 = 0000 0100 - run on 3rd core
               ↑
```

Simple code:

```
using (var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
{
  // only run on core number 1
  process.ProcessorAffinity = (IntPtr) 0x0001;
}
```