# Get processor affinity from matlab

Tags: matlab, processor, affinity

Is it possible to get processor affinity at run time from Matlab environment? If so how?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "get processor affinity"? And what are you going to do with that once you get it? Some background would be helpful.

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9778287/1214731 (I asked the question, it was nicely answered... so I don't want to take credit, but rather point you to that one)