# Windows Affinity

Tags: windows, cpu, affinity, setthreadaffinitymask

When setting the Windows CPU affinity mask for Core 2, is the mask supposed to be 0x0010 or 0x0001? I have seen an example where the mask was set to 0x0010 for Core 0 but this didn't make much sense?

Comment: Why doesn't that make sense? If it's a bitmask, 0x0001 makes perfect sense, it sets bit 0 to 1.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen because 0000  for Core....0 makes more sense?

Comment: If it's a bitmask, that would make no cores eligible. So no, it doesn't make more sense (to me). It's not the number of the core, it's a bitmask of which cores you allow.

Comment: Remember, this is a mask, not an enumeration. If 0000 means Core 0 only, how would you say "Both core 0 and core 1"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Example usage of SetProcessAffinityMask in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803585/example-usage-of-setprocessaffinitymask-in-c-c)

Answer (score 1):

`0x0000` allows no CPUs to be scheduled for this process/thread at all. (it will be suspended, assuming setting the affinity doesn't fail during parameter validation, which might be different on different Windows versions)

`0x0001` allows Core 0, only

`0x0002` allows Core 1, only

`0x0003` allows both Core 0 and Core 1.

Comment: Is affinity 0x0 really supported? I tried under Windows 7 and the call fails with error 87 (ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER).

Comment: I tried using NtSetInformationProcess with ProcessAffinityMask and reference to value 0x0 but that too fails with 0xC000000D (STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER).

Comment: @RolandPihlakas: Please read more carefully: *assuming setting the affinity doesn't fail during parameter validation, which might be different on different Windows versions*

Comment: Thanks for the details! Do You happen to remember on which Windows version affinity 0x0 did pass the parameter validation?

Comment: @RolandPihlakas: I don't know if there are any such versions at all, but the official documentation for the affinity functions doesn't promise that `0x0000` is always rejected as an invalid parameter, so you shouldn't rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can taskset it as well

```
("taskset -cp 2 %d"% os.getpid())
```