# Can i select my program using processor?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How Can I Set Processor Affinity in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510593/how-can-i-set-processor-affinity-in-net)

I have i7 930x . my computer have cpu 4core.And 8 processor(thread 8)
   so.. processor 1 , 2 ,3 ,4 .... 8.

but i want only number 1 processor. i don't want using other phsycal.

c# is possible?

example) my calc program using cpu No1.

```
        my sound program using cpu No2.<br>

        my Network A Program using cpu No1.<br>

        my Network B Program using cpu No3.<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to set a processor affinity mask for threads/processes to accomplish that. For some high performance programs using thread pools and work queues it can improve performance. In all other cases it is better to let the OS handle the scheduling.

Comment: Affinity is the term, but c# ...?

Comment: Is it possible to do in `net` itself?

Comment: See the duplicate I linked to. It contains sample code.