# VB.net Process Affinity

Tags: vb.net, process, affinity

**Goal:** My goal is to set all running processes's affinity to 1 core. Then launch a program with the affinity of all the cores.

**Skill Lvl:** My skill level in programming in general is pretty much beginner. This is my first language.

**Need:** I would like some help with this coding and maybe an article or description of the code. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a C# solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4219923/256431).

In summary, you need to loop through all processes (`Process.GetProcesses`) and set their `.ProcessorAffinity` to `New IntPtr(1)`, then start your new process. (The default is already to use all cores, but for completeness, if you want the new process to have a different affinity, set it after it's been started the same way as above.)

All the code:

```
Dim procs = Process.GetProcesses
For Each p In procs
 p.ProcessorAffinity = New IntPtr(1)
Next
Dim myProc = Process.Start("notepad.exe")
' Stop here to answer the OP.
' This sets the new Notepad process to be the only process running on the second CPU:
myProc.ProcessorAffinity = New IntPtr(2)
```