# C# limit application/service to number of CPU sockets/cores?

Tags: c#, .net

For example the SQL Server license model is limited to the number of cpu sockets/cores:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/compute-capacity-limits-by-edition-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

```
SQL Server edition
Maximum compute capacity for a single instance ( SQL Server Database Engine)
Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing*
Operating system maximum
Developer
Operating system maximum
Standard
Limited to lesser of 4 sockets or 24 cores
Express
Limited to lesser of 1 socket or 4 cores
```

**How do you limit the number of sockets or cores for an application or windows service in C#/.NET?**

*Is setting the processor affinity/threadaffinity the only way (which can easily be bypassed via task manager (ctrl+shift+esc))*

*(P.S.: The question is not if it is a good idea to do this or not, as seen a lot in other questions).*

Answer (score 1):

When you write a simple "hello world" c# program, this runs on one OS thread and one core.

If you want to stick to a single core, just don't spawn any threads or use any tasks.

You can limit the paralellism of the standard worker ThreadPool by using [`ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads?view=netframework-4.7.2). Some libraries might create their own thread pools, or their own worker threads. So you need to be more specific about your program in order to get a more complete answer.

If you want to limit yourself to a specific processor, you must also tweak the processor affinity of your process and threads. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510593/how-can-i-set-processor-affinity-in-net) for how to do that.
I don't know if you can tweak the affinity of the `ThreadPool` threads.