# Is there a way to limit the CPU usage of OTHER applications?

Tags: c#, cpu-usage

So, my brother was playing Fortnite and it was lagging quite a bit. So I offered to make an application that will limit the CPU usage of other apps, but I actually am having trouble with getting the limit to go on the *other* application.

Here's the code I've tried:

```cs
public void ThrottledLoop(Action action, int cpuPercentageLimit)
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

            while (true)
            {
                stopwatch.Reset();
                stopwatch.Start();

                long actionStart = stopwatch.ElapsedTicks;
                action.Invoke();
                long actionEnd = stopwatch.ElapsedTicks;
                long actionDuration = actionEnd - actionStart;

                long relativeWaitTime = (int)(
                    (1 / (double)cpuPercentageLimit) * actionDuration);

                Thread.Sleep((int)((relativeWaitTime / (double)Stopwatch.Frequency) * 1000));
            }
        }
```

Please help, if there is any other information you need just let me know.
Thanks

Comment: That's something the operating system would have to do, so your application would have to make a request into that.

Comment: FYI: A much simpler solution is to just set the game's process priority to a higher value, instead of trying to set everything else lower

Comment: Task manager -> end Task :)  or https://windowsreport.com/task-manager-set-priority/

Comment: oh i can do that? @UnholySheep

Comment: but what if i have unsaved stuff open? @TheGeneral

Comment: Or, thinking outside the square, just get a pc with more cores https://memegenerator.net/img/instances/71853357.jpg

Comment: You can also specify what **processors** (_"affinity"_) processes are allowed to run on.   This offers more fine grain control than setting process priority.  e.g.  limit them to say the _last 4 cores_ on a system with 16 logical cores but allowing Fortnite to use whatever it wants.  Be aware, some apps might not take too kindly to it. 
 For an example take a look at the Windows _Task Manager_ **Details** tab.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510593/how-can-i-set-processor-affinity-to-a-thread-or-a-task-in-net.

Comment: wait but what if i wanted to turn that handful of apps to 1 or 2 cores ONLY when the game is open?

Comment: @TheComputerWizard _"wait but what if i wanted to turn that handful of apps to 1 or 2 cores ONLY when the game is open?"_ I thought you wanted me to post it as an answer.  Please don't go changing the essence of the question after an answer has been posted

Comment: okay sorry... im just really bad at making questions (i only do it when nothing else is helpful)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

Summary from comments above.

---

You can specify what **processors** (*"affinity"*) processes are allowed to run on.   This offers more fine grain control than setting process priority.

e.g.  limit certain processes to say the *last 4 cores* on a system with 16 logical cores but allowing *Fortnite* to use whatever it wants.  Be aware, some apps might not take too kindly to it.

Anti-virus programs sometimes play nice by keeping themselves at the end of the list of cores in a system.

For an example take a look at the Windows *Task Manager* **Details** tab.

### See also

- [How can I set processor affinity to a thread or a Task in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510593/how-can-i-set-processor-affinity-to-a-thread-or-a-task-in-net)