# .NET Process - CPU control?

Tags: c#, process

I am having C# run a process in a new thread. The process takes 95 - 100% of my CPU. Is there a way I can tell the process to use less CPU? Do I need to tell the thread to do less CPU or the process?

Comment: What computations are you doing in the new thread that might be causing your issue? Posting code may help to clarify this.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/989281/how-can-i-programmatically-limit-my-programs-cpu-usage-to-below-70

Comment: What do you mean, "in a separate thread"? By definition, any new process will run on a new thread.

Answer (score 3):

There's no direct way to say "use less CPU". It seems like your operation is [CPU Bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_bound)

The best way to keep the CPU from being constantly burning at 100% utilization, is to invoke some direct threading control.  Put your main unit of work in a thread and call [Thread.Sleep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) after a unit of work has been executed.  As part of setting up a thread you can also use [Thread.Priority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.priority%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to set the priority (as you would via Task Manager).