# How can i limit cpu usage of windows processes using C#

Tags: c#, cpu-usage, thread-priority, cpu-time

I need to write a class that will attach to certain windows processes, monitor and limit their cpu usage.
Process priority changing would not help me at all so i really need to write a program that is basically similar to BES or ThreadMaster.
So i need to make a class that's doing something like this (pseudo code):

```
public void cpuLimiter(pid)
{
    ProcessHandle handle = attachToProcess(pid);
    while (cpuLimiting)
    {
        if (handle.cpuUsage > 30%)
        {
            handle.sleep(100miliseconds);
        }
        sleep(10miliseconds);
    }
    closeHandle(pid);
}
```

I hope i made it clear what i want to accomplish, just i have no idea how.
Every help is appreciated.

Comment: `beg you for the most complete code` This kind of makes it sound like you want us to just spoon-feed you a solution rather than addressing a specific problem with *code you've written*. The latter is a good question, the former is not. Please show what you've tried.

Comment: It is definitely going to be harder than what you think. Can't be answered in StackOverflow answer. Try something, run into a **specific** problem. Come here. We're happy to help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I programmatically limit my program's CPU usage to below 70%?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/989281/how-can-i-programmatically-limit-my-programs-cpu-usage-to-below-70)

Comment: tnw thanks for your remark, i agree with you, actually i didnt ask for a complete solution, i was just afraid if someone sends me to some assembly stuff, and i know i wouldnt even understand it

Comment: Is there any way to just send sleep(x miliseconds) to another process in windows? everything else i can improvise or i have already done, but i have no idea at all how to send sleep or suspend / start to another process in windows.

Comment: Are you programming in .NET C#? I had this issue with a console app that I created for Windows when I forgot to make the infinite while loop sleep. Make sure you call `System.Threading.Thead.Sleep(milliseconds)` in your infinite while loop in the Main() method of your program. That will reduce CPU usage, because if your infinite while loop does not sleep the CPU will spend a lot of time evaluating the condition of the while loop.

Answer (score 8):

- You create a JOB object
- You limit the CPU for the JOB
- you attach the target process to the JOB

See [Job Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161(v=vs.85).aspx#job_limits_and_notifications), [CreateJobObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682409(v=vs.85).aspx), [`SetInformationJobObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686216(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`JOBOBJECT_CPU_RATE_CONTROL_INFORMATION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448384(v=vs.85).aspx), [`AssignProcessToJobObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681949(v=vs.85).aspx). Do not attempt to hand-craft your own in-house process throttling, let the component specifically designed for this task (ie. jobs) handle the task.

See [Working example of CreateJobObject/SetInformationJobObject pinvoke in .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266820/working-example-of-createjobobject-setinformationjobobject-pinvoke-in-net) for managed usage of the NT Job native API.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your answer, it will take me lots of time to understand this so im gonna get on it.