# Is there any way in debian/ubuntu to put CPU under load until it reaches a certain temperature?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, cpu, temperature

I need this for some stress testing with my CPU. It uses Linux-Debian/Ubuntu OS and I was wondering if there's any way that I could put it under load until it reaches a certain temperature.

Are there any commands, packages or bash scripts for this?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download Prime95 from [here](https://www.mersenne.org/download/) or use any other CPU-Stress test that works under Debian/Ubuntu.

Get the following package:

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors
```

Start the sensors in terminal and update continously:

```
watch sensors
```

Now start Prime95 or your preferred stress-test and you can see cpu-temp inside terminal. Stop Stress test if cpu-temp exceeds your desired temperature. (modern cpu's are lowering clockspeed or shutting down automatically before damage from overheating is taken)

OR (automatically stopping at a user-specified temp)

Get the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors
sudo apt-get install stress
```

store the following code as bashfile i.e. `stresstest.sh` and run it with `sh /path/to/stresstest.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
sensors=/usr/bin/sensors

read_temp() {
    # get max Packagetemp from lm-sensors
    ${sensors} | grep 'Package' | awk '{print int($4)}'
}

echo 'Maximum CPU-Temperature:'
# insert tjMax manually
read tjMax

echo 'Workers for testing:'
# more workers cause higher load on the cpu
read workers

echo 'starting stress-test.'

pckgMax=$( read_temp )
while [ $tjMax -gt $pckgMax ]
do
    # update Packagetemp
    pckgMax=$( read_temp )
    # do 10sec stress-test
    # if you discover high temperature overhead, try lowering the --timeout
    stress --cpu ${workers} --timeout 10
done

echo 'reached tjMax.'
echo 'stopping stress-test.'
# kill this script and all running sub-processes
kill -- -0
```

Comment: If you have a lower target temperature, you might want to only load some of the cores, or use a lighter load than Prime95.  Prime95 on my system gets the CPU temp up to 65 C near instantly, climbing slowly upward from there towards 77C.  (Or higher with more aggressive energy_performance_preference.)

Comment: The problem is that I can't set a specific temperature to max out at with this tool.

Comment: @Leo I've updated my answer for a more automated approach in which you can enter a specific temperature to max out at. hope this helps.

Comment: TjMax is the standard name for the manufacturer's rated temperature limit (for junction temperature).  I'd suggest a different name for some target you're trying to reach, like TjTarget or TjThreshold.  If I saw a program print out "reached tjMax", I'd be worried about my CPU having been damaged if I hadn't read the script, so don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an existing software package (other than prime95 for *max* heating), but it's relatively easy to create loops with differing amounts of heat, like `awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<100000000;i++){}}'` keeps a CPU busy for a while making some heat.

See [How to write x86 assembly code to check the effect of temperature on the performance of the processor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41380921) for some suggestions on creating loops that heat the CPU more vs. less.

To hit a target temperature, you'll need to write some code to implement **[control loop](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Control_Systems/Feedback_Loops)** that reads the temperature (and the direction it's trending) and adjusts the load by starting/stopping threads, or changing up how power-intensive each thread is.  Without this feedback, you won't consistently hit a given CPU temperature; the actual temperature for an fixed workload will depend on ambient temp, how dusty your heat-sink is, and how the BIOS manages your fan speeds, etc.

Perhaps your CPU-heating threads could branch on a global `atomic` variable in an outer loop, so you can change what work they do by changing a variable.  e.g. 2 FMAs per clock, 1 FMA per clock, FMAs bottlenecked by latency (so 1 per 4 clocks), or just integer work, or a loop just running `pause` instructions, so it does the minimum.  Or 256-bit vs. 128-bit vs. scalar.

Perhaps also changing your EPP setting (on Intel Skylake or newer) with `sudo sh -c 'for i in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy[0-9]*/energy_performance_preference;do echo performance > "$i";done'` or `balance_performance` or `balance_power` (emphasize power-saving); these may affect what turbo clock speeds your CPU chooses to run at.

Read the temperature with lm-sensors, or by reading from the "coretemp" kernel driver directly on modern x86 hardware, e.g. `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon3/temp1_input` reads as `36000` for 36 degrees C.

```
$ grep . /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon3/*
/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon3/name:coretemp

/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon3/temp1_input:36000
/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon3/temp1_label:Package id 0

/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon3/temp2_input:35000
/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon3/temp2_label:Core 0

/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon3/temp5_input:33000
/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon3/temp5_label:Core 3
```

I'm not sure if the temperature is available directly to user-space without the kernel's help, e.g. via CPUID, on Intel or AMD.