# How to find an elapsed time of a C function in windows or linux

Tags: c, performance, timer, elapsedtime

I am doing some execution in a function `my_task`. I want to calculate how much time (or clock cycles) taken for CPU to execute this function, because I am going to do performance improvement on this function. So I refered [windows API](http://www.songho.ca/misc/timer/timer.html) and written the below code.

```
typedef struct timer
{
    LARGE_INTEGER t1;
    LARGE_INTEGER t2;
    LARGE_INTEGER frequency;
}MY_TIMER_S;

int start_timer(MY_TIMER_S *a)
{
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&a->frequency);
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&a->t1);
}

int stop_timer(MY_TIMER_S *a)
{
    double elsapsedtime;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&a->t2);
    elapsedtime = (a->t2.QuadPart - a->t1.QuadPart) * 1000.0 / a->frequency.QuadPart;
    printf("Elapsed time is %lf ms\n", elapsedtime);
}

void main()
{
    MY_TIMER_S a = {0};
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        start_timer(&a);
        my_task();
        stop_timer(&a); 
    }
}
```

Output is

```
Elapsed time is 0.113352 ms
Elapsed time is 0.203253 ms
Elapsed time is 0.104254 ms
```

These three values are accurate to nano seconds, but not precision. I thought like this because of process switching happened by other applications which is parallely runing in my system. I checked my task manager it was showing as 124 processes running. So I restarted my system (now 84 process in task manager) and then the output is

```
Elapsed time is 0.083162 ms
Elapsed time is 0.113223 ms
Elapsed time is 0.074258 ms
```

After than I executed my exe with `start /high` [command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208/windows-equivalent-of-nice), then also I am not getting precision values.

My question is how to calculate an elapsed time of a function in more precision way in windows or linux.

Environment : 32 Bit Windows 7 on i5 processor, 4Gb ram with Visual Studio 2005 C compiler

Comment: The most basic answer is to run your task many times (like 100,000) so that the overhead becomes a smaller part of the overall runtime.

Comment: unwind and msam are right. What's more, forget precision. If whatever speedup you can do to it requires more than 2 digits of precision to see, you may as well not even bother.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    start_timer(&a);
    my_task();
    stop_timer(&a); 
}
```

do

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
  start_timer(&a);
  for (j = 0; j < 30000; j++)
  {        
    my_task();        
  }
  stop_timer(&a); 
}
```