# how to nice Jupiter notebook from conda

Tags: linux, conda, nice

I am trying to set less than 0 niceness value (high priority) for Jupiter notebook.

Everything is based on conda environment

Firstly, this runs without any issue:

```
jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --port 8888;
```

I tried:

```
$ nice -n -1 jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --port 8888;
nice: cannot set niceness: Permission denied
```

Then I tried

```
$ sudo nice -n -1 jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --port 8888;
nice: ‘jupyter’: No such file or directory
```

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR;** I think because you are giving `-1` as a parameter. The Standard is 20, at least in my Linux system. Try giving it a different value, that is still positive like 1.

```bash
nice -n 1 jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --port 8888
```

### During my research:

Have you tried the [`su` command](https://linuxize.com/post/su-command-in-linux/) for switching users, but we will use it to execute the command with `-c` flag as [discussed here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/72959).

```bash
sudo nice -n -1 su -c <command_to_run> <user_to_run_as>
```

I have tried to reproduce your error, but couldn't do it. Maybe it has to do with the fact that there [are 2 different versions](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/change-the-nice-value-of-a-process/), `bin/nice and nice from bash`. Check documentation with `man nice`.

I am assuming you are using Linux OS, by the use of `nice` command, but if anyone needs a similar thing for Windows, [should look into the equivalent of `nice` here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4332/10985412).

Comment: Thanks! The issue is actually that root user cannot don't have the PATH parameter for Jupiter. But I think `sudo nice -n -1 su -c <command_to_run> <user_to_run_as>
` is the ultimate solution. Do you know how to put my commands there? Like `sudo nice -n -1 su -c jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --port 8888 my username
` ? Thanks!

Comment: @user40780 `sudo nice -n -1 su -c "jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --port 8888" <user_name>` sounds right to me, but would have to activate environment with the appropriate knowledge of `jupyter`. Maybe  `sudo nice -n -1 su -c "conda activate <env> && jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --port 8888" <user_name>`